# update mysql with form data after uploading file to s3 using lambda python

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to upload a file to S3 using a form. The form also has several other data and although the file does upload to the bucket, I just don't understand how to get the rest of the data to use it in a Lambda function to update a mysql database in an RDS instance.

Here is my form (adapted from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html)

```
    <form name='form10' action="http://<?= $my_bucket ?>.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return v.exec()">
        <input type="hidden" name="key" value="videos/${filename}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read" />
        <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Credential" value="<?= $access_key; ?>/<?= $short_date; ?>/<?= $region; ?>/s3/aws4_request" />
        <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" />
        <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Date" value="<?=$iso_date ; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="Policy" value="<?=base64_encode($policy); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature" value="<?=$signature ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="<?= $success_redirect ?>" /> 

        <table summary="Playlist de Campa&ntilde;a" align=center border="1">
            <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">Agregar Videos a Playlist</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Selecciona tu Archivo:</td><td><input type="file" name="file" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Descripci&oacute;n del Video</td><td><input type="text" name="desc_video" value="" size="50"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Fecha Inicio:
                <input type=text name=start_date value="<?PHP echo $fecha_inicio; ?>"><a href="javascript:show_calendar('form10.start_date');" ><img src="images/show-calendar.gif" width="24" height="22" border="0" alt=""></a>
                </td><td>Fecha Terminaci&oacute;n
                <input type=text name=end_date value="<?PHP echo $fecha_termina;?>"><a href="javascript:show_calendar('form10.end_date');" ><img src="images/show-calendar.gif" width="24" height="22" border="0" alt=""></a>
                </td></tr>
            <tr><td>Hora Inicio:
                    <select name="hora_inicio">
                        <?PHP 
                        for ($hr = 0; $hr < 24; $hr++){
                            echo"<option value=$hr>$hr</option>";
                        } 
                        ?>
                            </select>:
                    <select name="mins_inicio">
                        <?PHP 
                        for ($hr = 0; $hr < 60; $hr+=5){
                            echo"<option value=$hr>$hr</option>";
                        } 
                        ?>
                        <option value="59">59</option>
                    </select></td>
            <td>Hora Terminaci&oacute;n:
                    <select name="hora_final">
                        <?PHP 
                        for ($hr = 0; $hr < 24; $hr++){
                            if($hr<>23){
                               echo"<option value=$hr>$hr</option>"; 
                            } else {
                               echo"<option value=$hr selected>$hr</option>"; 
                            }

                        } 
                        ?>
                            </select>:
                    <select name="mins_final">
                        <?PHP 
                        for ($hr = 0; $hr < 60; $hr+=5){
                            echo"<option value=$hr>$hr</option>";
                        } 
                        ?>
                        <option value="59" selected>59</option>
                    </select></td>        
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Continuar" /></td></tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="step" value="sube" />
        <input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="<?PHP echo $tipo; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="id_campana" value="<?PHP echo $id_campana; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="fecha_inicio" value="<?PHP echo $fecha_inicio; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="fecha_termina" value="<?PHP echo $fecha_termina; ?>" />

    </form>
```

So as you can see, I have a bunch of variables that I need to save to my database, and I just don't get how to call them up on the Lambda function. The Lambda function can write to the database. I have a hardcoded sql statement that is able to write to the database, and it triggers by itself when the S3 bucket receives a file. 
This is the lambda function I am using, (adapted from: https://www.isc.upenn.edu/accessing-mysql-databases-aws-python-lambda-function)

```
import sys
import logging
import rds_config
import pymysql
#rds settings
rds_host  = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com"
name = rds_config.db_username
password = rds_config.db_password
db_name = rds_config.db_name
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

try:
 conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, db=db_name, connect_timeout=5)
except:
 logger.error("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySql instance.")
 sys.exit()
logger.info("SUCCESS: Connection to RDS mysql instance succeeded")
def lambda_handler(event, context):
 try:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO archivos (id_cliente,id_campana,tipo_asset,id_tipo_asset,file_name,original_name,descripcion,file_type,date_begin,date_end,time_begin,time_end,MD5) VALUES (5,11,'Marca',3,'test.png','test.png','este es el video','png','2017-08-01','2017-08-30','00:00:00','23:59:00','90175908345798dhf')")
    conn.commit()
 except MySQLError as e:
    logger.error(e)
 return None
```

Any ideas on how I could accomplish this? I am sure it is something really silly, but I have been trying to do it for days now and I just can't seem to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have everything successfully uploaded to S3, you can create a trigger from S3 to Lambda. The event contains all the information about the S3 object uploaded.

You can also read the S3 object, extract the fields you want and store it to RDS.

Below is the documentation to create S3 Trigger to Lambda.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html

You can also customize the trigger based on new post, update or delete.

Hope this helps.

Comment: my question is how to extract the fields. I don't know how to do that part. I can upload, trigger the lambda, write to the RDS but not how to get the fields from the form. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure of the question. What do you mean format? It is either a video or picture.

Comment: When you do a post with multiform data. It is file and as well as data. If you are only posting file to s3, you can take the data to a lambda endpoint and process through file. In this case you need to do two posts, one for S3 and another for lamba post for form parameters. If you post it to lambda, it will be posted as json data.

Comment: So I cannot receive the data on the s3 and then "relay" it to the Lambda? Sorry to ask these basic questions, but I am new to AWS.

Comment: If you have uploaded multipart data to S3. It should be stored in the S3 object as json file. Image I assume as base64 data. You can read those file and parse those json object to get your data.

Comment: And how do I call it in my Python code? I don't know what variable to call.

Comment: http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/s3/python/#download-an-object-to-a-file . --  check this link on how to download an object